# Variation with repetitions into null set.

Tags: combinatorics

Let's consider a set with the following elements:

$ S = \{a, b, c\}$

If we have $D = 2$ place holders for each element of set $S$ and there might be repetitions and the order is relevant, then we have the following set of results:

```
{a, a}
{a, b}
{a, c}
{b, a}
{b, b}
{b, c}
{c, a}
{c, b}
{c, c}
```

The general pattern is $|R| = |S|^{|D|}$.

Now, let us consider two extremes.

1. $S = \{\}, |S| = 0, |D| > 0$. What is the result? $R = \{\}$, $|R| = 0^{|D|} = 0$. That I understand. There is no elements in the source $S$, so the result set $R$ exists and is empty.
2. $S = \{a, b, c\}, |S| = 3, |D| = 0$. What is the result? $|R| = 3^0 = 1$. Hm, What? `R` is not empty? **What element should be in $R$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique element of $R$ is the empty sequence. It is the only $0$-element sequence that can be constructed using elements of $S$. (Note that the elements of $R$ are not actually subsets of $S$, as you’ve written them, because you’re taking order into account; they are, rather, sequences of $D$ elements of $S$, i.e., $D$-tuples of elements of $S$.)

Comment: `R = {{}}` with no regard how many elements is in `S`?

Comment: @yBee: That’s correct: the empty sequence $\langle\rangle$ is the same no matter what objects are in $S$, or how many of them there are.